# Java - The constructor Seller(int, String, String, Date, double, int) is undefined

Tags: java, dao

**Pessoal, estou tomando erro de exception ao compilar este código no Java - Eclipse: O erro ocorre na classe Program.java

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The constructor Seller(int, String, String, Date, double, int) is undefined

```
at PROJETO_DAO_JDBC_SELLER/application.Program.main(Program.java:14)`
```

**

```
Classe Program.java

package application;

import java.util.Date;

import model.entities.Department;
import model.entities.Seller;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Department obj = new Department(1,"Books");
        
        Seller seller = new Seller(21,"Bob", "bob@gmail.com", new Date(), 3000.0, obj);
        
        System.out.println(seller);
        }
}
```

**Abaixo a classe Seller! Pode ver que ela possui o metodo construtor e está correto**

```
package model.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Seller implements Serializable{
    
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Date birhDate;
    private double baseSalary;
    
    private Department department;
    
    public Seller (){
    }

    public Seller(Integer id, String name, String email, Date birhDate, double baseSalary, Department department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.birhDate = birhDate;
        this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getBirhDate() {
        return birhDate;
    }

    public void setBirhDate(Date birhDate) {
        this.birhDate = birhDate;
    }

    public double getBaseSalary() {
        return baseSalary;
    }

    public void setBaseSalary(double baseSalary) {
        this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Seller other = (Seller) obj;
        return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Seller [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", birhDate=" + birhDate + ", baseSalary="
                + baseSalary + ", department=" + department + "]";
    }
    
    
        
}
```

Tentei comparar com os códigos do professor e estão iguais, os construtores estão corretos ao meu ver. e o Department obj = new Department(1,"Books"); está funcionando.

Comment: Change `import java.sql.Date;` to `import java.util.Date;` in `Seller.java`.

Comment: @DwB  I count six for both.  The issue is the mismatched Date class.

Comment: This is an English site so please post questions and answers in English.

Comment: The solution Change import java.sql.Date; to import java.util.Date; in Seller.java did not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you're using `java.sql.Date` which doesn't have a no-args constructor (see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)). So using a valid constructor should work.